# Get source of each image in div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a seemingly simple loop, but I keep running into issues.

I'm trying to loop through a specific div (targeted by an ID), and return the source of the two images inside of it. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="row selected" id="one"><img src="onei.png"><img src="twoi.png"></div>
   <div class="row" id="two"><img src="onei1.png"><img src="twoi2.png"></div>
 </div>
```

And here is my loop:

```
function loop() {
    alert()
    $('#container row.selected img').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('src'))
    });
}
```

I can't seem to find out why this isn't working. Shouldn't this loop through each image in my targeted div and alert the source?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

maybe something like

```
function loop() {
    alert()
    $('#container .row.selected img').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('src'))
    });
}
```

you forgot the `.` on `row`

Comment: Super simple mistake! Thanks for providing me sanity!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you missed the point:

```
'#container .row.selected img'
```