# jQuery syntax to access the SRC of a class

Tags: jquery, syntax

I have been trying for an hour or more to guess the syntax to get the attribute of an element in jQuery.

The img src (and the other attributes) are located here:

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">     
  <li class="userList">
    <div class="selectedItemId" id="15974">
      <img class="selectedItemImg" src="http://asdasd.jpg" alt="Terror" in="" resonance="" style="width:216px;height:300px">
      <div id="animeTitle">Terror in Resonance</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The attributes are generated on-the-go when the user drags them into the list so I can't call `"id=15974"` for instance.

When the user clicks the button I want to loop through the contents of the sortable2 list and fetch the attributes of the child objects (their image srcs as a starting point).

Please could some genius have a quick look and maybe point me in the right direction for my syntax?

So far (among many many attempts) I am sitting with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function () {
    alert("Hello!");
    $('.userList .selectedItemId .selectedItemImg img').each(function() {
      alert($(this).attr('src'));
      alert("Hello2");
    });
  });
});
```

Currently nothing happens apart from "Hello1". I had Hello2 working in many attempts but no luck with the data.

Thankyou for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for an image inside image, try this

```
$('.userList .selectedItemId .selectedItemImg').each(function() {
                                           //Removed img
    alert(this.src);//You can use this.src instead of .attr()
    alert("Hello2");
});
```

Comment: It works, you are brilliant, well done and thankyou. I was using this syntax as a reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709797/get-source-of-each-image-in-div-with-jquery You can see there that he seems to be doing what I was doing but says it works. He writes: ` $('#container .row.selected img').each(function() {` Anyway, thankyou ever so much

Comment: Quick update, I screwed up: the actual working syntax is `$('#sortable2 .selectedItemImg').each(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function () {
        $('img.selectedItemImg').each(function() {
              alert($(this).attr('src'));
        });
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/vipolologi/1/

Comment: Quick update, I screwed up: the actual working syntax is `$('#sortable2 .selectedItemImg').each(function() {`